# Excel matching data thats not there

Tags: excel

i have been trying to compare a single value to an entire column. and currently every answer it gives is YES even to a value that wont match.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$K:$K,0)),"YES","NO"
```

this is the formula i used. any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:
sample data (there is over 4k records like this)

```
A               B            K
99/M/9/99       YES       99/M/9/99
99/M/9/98       NO        99/M/9/97
99/M/9/97       YES
```

Comment: I think excel incorectly treats #NA as a number here....
try using ISNA()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula: `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A4,$K:$K,0),"YES"),"NO")`